# Datetime! Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried converting a column with timestamp from `nvarchar` to `datetime` (as I wasn't sure that by exporting Excel to SQL Server the precision within timestamp won't be lost), but the column still won't convert, showing the same error all the time

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - convert

I tried

```
alter table X 
    alter column [Timestamp] datetime
```

and I also tried:

```
convert(datetime, [Timestamp], 103)
try_convert(datetime, [Timestamp], 103)
cast ([Timestamp] as datetime)
```

still no progress.

This is the sample data from the column:

```
2019-02-13-13.01.05.6100000015
2019-02-18-13.10.46.4850000015
```

Could you please help?

Comment: manipulate the string so it is like this:  DECLARE @d varchar(255) = '2019-02-18 13:10:46.485'; SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, @d);

Comment: Three points. First, a `DATETIME` is only precise to three decimal places after the seconds. You would be looking for a `DATETIME2(7)` data type.  Second, a `DATETIME2(7)` data type is only precise to seven decimal places, but your data contains ten decimal places. You will lose precision with any datetime data type in SQL Server. Third, the `CONVERT` format in this context should be matching that of the timestamp, but it does not. Your best bet would be to reformat the value into a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, e.g. `2019-02-13 13:01:05.6100000' and then `CONVERT` it.

Comment: Alternately, if you are looking to output only the date information, try `CONVERT(Date, SUBSTRING([Timestamp], 1, 10))`

Comment: Thanks everyone! So this means I still have to manipulate the strings in raw data before converting... is there any other time-efficient way to avoid it, as the data is already in SQL?

Comment: Also, you can check for data in the field that cannot map to a datetime.  For example, 219-02-13 13:01:05.610 will cause an error as AD 219 is not out of range.  So you can also search for date values prior to the datetime start, which is around AD 1754

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select 
    try_convert(datetime2(7), 
                 STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE('2019-02-18-13.10.46.485000015','.',':'), 11, 1, ' '),20,1,'.')
               ,121)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to change the type to a [DATETIME2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) since it has a higher precision than DATETIME.

First change the format of the timestamp strings to a format that can be casted to a `DATETIME2` without problem.

```
UPDATE X
SET [Timestamp] = CONCAT(LEFT([Timestamp],10), 'T', REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Timestamp],12,8),'.',':'),  '.', SUBSTRING([Timestamp],21,9))
WHERE [Timestamp] LIKE '[12][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[01][0-9]_[0-3][0-9]_[0-2][0-9].[0-6][0-9].[0-6][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%';
```

Then double check if there are still some that can't be casted as-is.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) Errors, MAX([Timestamp]) Example
FROM X
WHERE TRY_CAST([Timestamp] AS DATETIME2) IS NULL;
```

If the count was 0 then the type of the column can be changed.

```
ALTER TABLE X 
  ALTER COLUMN [Timestamp] DATETIME2(7);
```

A test on rextester [here](https://rextester.com/QLEW46246)

Do notice that some precision will be lost.